# tool that shows javascript errors in code

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jsfiddle, plunker

While debugging in `Console` in `IE` or any other browser, it shows the javascript errors. I was wondering if there are any tools like plunkr or jsfiddle that shows the javascript issues (and i can show the code issues to other users on websites like SO) even when the functionality works fine. For ex. I have created [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/enHuKjfL7ZPj7SvBCUZ2?p=preview) piece of code in plunkr and it shows the code works as expected, but while debugging in console in browser, it gives errors. Does even plunkr or jsfiddle have this functionality?

Comment: To clarify: Are you asking for some Javascript, executable in the client, that renders a full suite of debugging tools, inside your HTML-flow? ... if that is the case, i'm pretty sure, that none exists ... and I can’t imagine why you don’t just use (any) browsers built-in capabilities.

Comment: I dont know about other forums but on SO, you can share the code or share a fiddle, plunker and what not. While we run your code/fiddle we would get the errors on our browser console. Thats about it! We can check the errors. And more over you can take a print screen of your console showing errors post the image here, mention the matching line numbers in the question and we could relate to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Closure Tools from google:

https://developers.google.com/closure/

Especially you want Closure Linter, shows also fixes errors:

https://developers.google.com/closure/utilities/

Best of luck.

(Mark this as answer if this serves your need)

Comment: Do these tools satisfy *(and i can show the code issues to other users on websites like SO)* condition of OP?

Comment: Sure. It logs errors with details, per error line, that can be shared on websites.